# Is it safe to see smartphone first thing in the morning?

Tags: eye, safety

Well, I'm a student and have many interesting things to learn, but not enough time. So, one thing I'm trying is that I pick one of the things that I really want to learn, but can't make time for, then the moment alarm rings I resume the video that I setup to learn at night. Then I'm on screen for like 15-20mins.

This style not only gets the thing done, but also motivates me to wake up in the morning. But I'm worried if it may damage my eyes since they are getting exposed to these radiations immediately after a long period of relaxation.

It would be of immense help if you could give me some information regarding this concern. Thanks!

Comment: Looking outside on a sunny morning exposes your eyes to much stronger radiation and yet that's what humans have been doing for millions of years without harm.

Comment: Your eyes are designed to percieve light. The problems arise only when there is constant stimulation(addictive behaviours, long work hours), strong stimulation(high intensity light), less light or when your eye muscles are strained due to any reason(holding the screen too close).